# Given a target's name, get all of its prerequisites

Tags: makefile

If I have a makefile with e.g.:

```
foo.o: foo.c a.h b.h c.h
    cc -c foo.c -o foo.o
```

Now, in some other part of the makefile, I want to get all the prerequsites of `foo.o`, like I'd do with `$^` in the recipe. Something like:

```
$(info $(call GET_TARGET_PREREQS(foo.o))) # prints "foo.c a.h b.h c.h"
```

Basically, I have dependency files (generated by `-M`) for all my object files, and from there I want a list of all the header files that are included by a given object.

I'm hoping for a more or less pure make solution, and not a sed script that parses the `*.d` files and outputs makefile fragments.

Comment: That's cool you're using `-M`, but why would you need a list of headers files included by a given object elsewhere?

Comment: @JulienPalard I'm writing a tool that runs at build time, and I need a list of all the headers that the project will be using (So, I'm looking for an aggregate of all objects' headers). A simple `find . -name "*.h"` won't work because not all headers are actually used, depending on build configuration. So I need to run all the sources through `-M`, see what they include and then put that in a make-readable list.

Comment: You're writing a tool that runs at build time and needs a list of a target's prerequisites, but you don't want to invoke it in that target's rule... And you want "a more or less pure make solution". It really sounds as if Make is not the right tool for what you have in mind.

Comment: I'm not sure I'm getting it right, the "tool that run at build time" is not a "builder" ? Because if it is, `-M` actually IS your make-readable list... Does this helps: http://make.mad-scientist.net/papers/advanced-auto-dependency-generation/ ?

Comment: Just to cover the basics: there is no way to obtain the prerequisite list for some arbitrary other target, using a "pure make solution".

Comment: Minor nit: `$<` is the first prerequisite; `$^` are all the prerequisites.

Comment: @MadScientist Fair enough, thanks. I'll go with sed to parse the `.d` file into a make-readable list. @tripleee Thanks, fixed. @JulienPalard It is, in the given recipe, but you can't assign those values to a variable, you can't call any functions on it, etc. Thanks all.

Comment: Just for completeness: you can call functions on automatic variables, but those variables only have the value you want within their own rule's recipe.  You can also assign automatic variables to other variables (using `eval`) but this will only help if you've already run the recipe for the other target before you try to use the variable.

Comment: @mtijanic, consider starting looking for GNU make alternatives. The question is the sure sign that you are trying hard to workaround some make limitation. Been there, done that. Start looking for alternatives. P.S. You can try to get the parsed dependency info from the output of the `make -p` (very quirky and hacky workaround).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to print all prerequsites, you can always use $^

```
.PONY: all

all: a b c
         @echo $^
a:
b:
c:
```

Comment: But that is only valid in the recipe for `all`. What I needed was to get all prereqs for `all` inside of `a`. Or even outside of all other recipes (e.g. below all the code you provided). See comments about MadScientist above for why this isn't possible.
Thanks, though.